# MultipartFile getting set as Null with spring3 and rest cxf

Tags: rest, file-upload, jax-rs, multipartform-data, spring-3

I am trying to upload a xls.
I have written below Rest Web service

```
@POST
@Path("/ui/uploadDocument")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public void uploadDocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file )
```

I have also added below to the spring application context config:

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="99999"/>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="99999"/>
</bean>
```

Now I am trying to run the above using Chrome rest client and simple html code like below:

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/my-core/eCom/v1/catalogue/ui/uploadDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br /> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

The problem I am facing from both rest client or invoking it via html code is that though the rest call is successfully called but the file(MultipartFile) is set as null.
Have I missed any setting above ?

We are using spring 3.0 and for rest support we are using apache jaxrs...
Anyones help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by doing the jax rs way.

Below is the code :

```
@POST
@Path("/ui/uploadDocument")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response uploadDocument(List<Attachment> attachments, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {   
     for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
        DataHandler handler = attachment.getDataHandler();
        try {
     //            Creates a workbook object from the uploaded excelfile
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(handler.getInputStream());
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= worksheet.getLastRowNum()) {
                HSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i++);
                CatDefault catDefault = new CatDefault();
                catDefault.setCatId((long) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
             }
        }
     }
```

HTML code used to invoke is as below:

```
<form action="http://localhost/cat-core/eCom/v1/catalogue/ui/uploadDocument" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" size="50" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

Link [CXF](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/05/cxf-rest-file-upload?page=1) was useful.